# Is there a comprehensive list of uncontested elections for head of state?

Tags: election, data-sources, head-of-state

Regarding the upcoming election of the next Hong Kong SAR Chief Executive (CE) on 2022-05-08: As of 2022-05-03, various news outlets report that [John Lee Ka-chiu (李家超)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Lee_(government_official)) is running uncontested.  In theory, this could change in the next few days.  For this Q&A, please assume that it will not change.

Is there a comprehensive list of uncontested elections for head of state?

Thinking more deeply while writing this question: This question may be *more* relevant for for presidential systems.  For parlimentary systems, you would need to have *all* seats uncontested, then the Prime Minister would be virtually guaranteed, excluding party rebellion / split during gov't formation.  (Surprise me!  For example: Was Saddam Hussein or Muammar Gaddafi every elected, uncontested as head of state in a parlimentary system?)  Also, I am not concerned about presidents in parliamentary systems (like Germany), nor prime ministers in presidential systems (like France).

I do realise the term "head of state" is complex.  Take Australia for example: If you asked most non-Australians, they would not say (currently) Queen Elizabeth II.  They would say Prime Minister Scott Morrison.  It might be better to rephase this question as "the most senior/powerful executive positive".  Another rabbit hole to consider: Finland has both (indirectly elected) Prime Minister and (directly elected) President that share power for complex historical reasons.

Finally, I am aware that only a small committee of about 1,400 people cast final ballots to elect the HKSAR CE.

Comment: Might "[head of government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_of_government)" be a better term? It typically refers to the Prime Minister in a parliamentary state, and the President in a presidential state (where the President is also head of state). In semi-presidential states, it's a bit more complex.

Comment: "For parliamentary systems, you would need to have all seats uncontested": it typically only requires a majority to approve (or fail to remove) a PM; so control of just over 50% of the seats would be sufficient.

Comment: You would need a system were even becoming a candidate on the ballot is heavily restricted otherwise there would be some fringe candidates even if the outcome is already certain beforehand.

Comment: A direct answer may be less helpful than you might assume.  A number of elections in totalitarian states are not uncontested but nevertheless have no realistic contenders.  For example, the CCP in China allows some parties to run (though I am not sure at what level).  Are they therefore *contested* elections?  You'd have to be very very gullible to think that.  So then you have to get into the business of opinionating whether an opponent is a realistic opponent or not.  Even a massively popular politician projected to win with 90% isn't necessarily a rigged election if they are truly popular.

Comment: You mention Hong Kong, which isn't an independent state. So are you accepting elections to leaders of subnational entities?